# how to offset thumbnails by a fixed number (say 5) on clicking the left/right navigation buttons in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, thumbnails, offset

Could someone please guide me create the navigation (left and right) used for thumbnail gallery in this site - 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/images/

Basically I want the left and right buttons to offset the thumbnails by some number (say 6 as in this example).

I do not want fancy fade in or slide in/out effects, just a simple navigation to do the offsetting part.

I'm totally new to JS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state your totaly new to JS this might be hard to accomplish but I would suggest you look at using one of the most common JS frameworks availble, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). jQuery makes building JS a lot faster but also a lot easier, and another bonus is there are multiple plugins for jQuery that has already solved your problem.

Like in your case the (MB)SCROLLABLE plugin would probably help you a lot and you'll find examples on how to use it on this site: http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.scrollable/scrollable.html

Hope that could get you started.